# I've got `-inf` when calculating on rust: what is `-inf`?

Tags: math, rust

The following code produces the result `-inf`.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (-10. / 0.));
}
```

However, when I tried the following code, it didn't print `true`, instead it gave me an error.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (-10. / 0.) == -inf);
}
```

What value should I give instead of `-inf` to get `true` printed out?

Comment: It's part of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), the [floating point](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#floating-point-types) spec.

Comment: minus infinity!

Comment: `0/-10` would give you `0`, not `-inf`. Do you mean `-10/0`?

Comment: "I expected that -inf == -inf would return true but it didn't work." Can you be more specific? What specifically did you try and how did it not work? Negative infinity should indeed compare equal to itself and [it does for me on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=36222fc5715b1d1688c1eaef3dfab913)

Comment: Please build a [MRE]. It's hard to understand what you tested and how you deduced that `-inf==-inf` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by sepp2k, `-inf` is not valid Rust syntax. To check for infinite values, try `f64::is_finite()` or comparing to constants `std::f64::INFINITY` and `std::f64::NEG_INFINITY`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let result: f64 = -10. / 0.;
    println!("{}", result.is_infinite()); // true
    println!("{}", result == std::f64::INFINITY); // false
    println!("{}", result == std::f64::NEG_INFINITY); // true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> what is `-inf`?

It's negative infinity as defined in the IEEE floating point standard. It's the result of dividing negative floating point numbers by zero.

> However, when I tried the following code, it didn't print true, instead it gave me an error.
>
> ```
> fn main() {
>     println!("{}", (-10. / 0.) == -inf);
> }
> ```

Rust does not define a global variable or keyword named `inf`. So you can't use `inf` unless you first define (or import from somewhere) a variable with that name. `-inf` is just the string you get when converting negative infinity to a string. It's not a valid floating point literal by itself.

> What value should I give instead of -inf to get true printed out?

You could use the constants `INFINITY` or `NEG_INFINITY` from the given floating point type, such as `-10. / 0. == std::f64::NEG_INFINITY` or `-10. / 0. == -std::f64::INFINITY`. Or you could define `let inf = 1. / 0.;`, then `(-10. / 0.) == -inf` would be true. Or you could just directly write `-10. / 0. == -1. / 0.` or any other expression that results in negative infinity.

> What type is `-inf`?

The type of `-inf` is the same as that of the floating point numbers that you divided to get `-inf`. If you divide two `f32`s, you'll get an `f32`, and if you divide two `f64`s, you'll get an `f64`. If the type of the operands hasn't been decided yet, the type of the result will be `{float}` until a more concrete type has been decided.

Note that this isn't any different than any other case of dividing two floating point numbers (or adding them, multiplying them etc.). In other words, `x / y` where `y` is 0. has the exact same type as `x / y` where `y` is any other floating point number.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Thanks, I've added `NEG_INFINITY` to my answer.